# Proving an inequality using elementary manipulations

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I am trying to prove the following inequality:

$$
\prod_{r=2}^{n} \left(1+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)<2 \qquad \forall n\geq 2 
$$

Since this problem was taken from chapter-1 of *Algebraic Inequalities* (by Hayk and Nairi Sedrakyan), I expect to be able to prove it using basic manipulations. In particular, I am allowing myself to use the AM-GM inequality for two terms but not the generalized version since I haven't proven it yet.

I tried the following approach
$$
1+\frac{1}{r^2}<1+\frac{1}{r} \\
\implies \prod_{r=2}^{n} \left(1+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)<\prod_{r=2}^{n} \left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right)
$$

However, the product on the right blows up, so that is not useful. At this point, I am quite stuck.

**Disclosure**: I am self-studying inequalities from the above-mentioned textbook - this is not a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you're after, but here is a quick verification. Using: $\ 1 + x < e^x\ \forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0},$

$$ \prod_{k=2}^n \left( 1 + \frac{1}{k^2} \right) < \prod_{k=2}^n \exp\left({\frac{1}{k^2}}\right) = \exp\left({\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2}}\right) < \exp\left( \frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1 \right) = 1.9\ldots <2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Prove the stronger statement that for $ n \geq 4$,

$$ \prod_{r=2}^n ( 1 + \frac{1}{r^2})  <2 - \frac{2}{r}.$$

Verify that the base case of $ n = 4$ is true.
(It doesn't hold for $ n = 2, 3$, which is why I chose $n = 4$ as the starting point).

The induction step follows from showing that

$$ ( 2 - \frac{2}{n} ) ( 1 + \frac{ 1}{ (n+1)^2 } ) < 2 - \frac{2}{n+1} \Leftrightarrow n(n+1)^2 > 0. $$

Then go back and verify $ n = 2, 3$ for the original problem.

---

Another stronger statement (which offers a tighter bound) is for $ n \geq 8$

$$ \prod_{r=2}^n ( 1 + \frac{1}{r^2} ) < 2 - \frac{1}{ \sqrt{r} } . $$

In this case, while the statement is verifiably true for all $n$ (as opposed to the above), the induction step only works for $ n \geq 9$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain the thought process that went into deciding that proving a stronger statement would be fruitful?

Comment: I tried to prove a few things by induction, starting with $ \prod_{r=2}^n ( 1 + \frac{1}{r^2})  <2 - \frac{1}{r},$ but none of the induction steps worked. What made you suspect that $ \prod_{r=2}^n ( 1 + \frac{1}{r^2})  <2 - \frac{2}{r} $ would work?

Comment: @TVina I personally call it "stronger induction" (it's not a standard term), and use it for cases like this. For the naive induction, the LHS increases but the RHS stays constant, so that will not work. Instead, if we changed the RHS to be an increasing function bounded above by the constant, then we have a hope of proving it. So we have to find such a function, and playing around yields $2 - 2/n$ as a nice candidate.

Comment: @AdamRubinson The form that you're choosing could be generalized to $ 2 - c/n$ for some constant $c$. Then, it remains to find a $c$ such that in our domain (ideally $n \geq 1$, but at least on $[D, \infty)$) $(2 - c/n) ( 1 + 1/(n+1)^2) < 2 - c/(n+1) $. Play with it, or use Wolfram, to show that $ c = 2, n > 0 $ works. Then, figure out how to apply it. $\quad$ EG I gave another example where the form is $ 2 - c / \sqrt{r}$, and what happens there after. While the base case works immediately, the domain is now $ n \geq 9$.

Comment: @TVina You cannot prove the original statement $
\prod_{r=2}^{n} \left(1+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)<2 \qquad \forall n\geq 2 
$ by induction because $
\prod_{r=2}^{k} \left(1+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)<2
$ does not imply that $
\prod_{r=2}^{n+1} \left(1+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)<2.  
$ However, if we prove a stronger statement by induction, we can (hopefully) then deduce from that stronger statement that $
\prod_{r=2}^{n} \left(1+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)<2 \qquad \forall n\geq 2 .
$

Comment: That makes sense! I had tried "naive" induction and failed for precisely this reason.