# How to choose which stronger claim to prove when proving $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \le 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, inequality, summation, proof-writing

I am studying an inductive proof of the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \le 2$. In the proof, it was decided to prove the stronger claim $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \le 2-\frac{1}{n}$, as this was easier to prove, and to use this to prove $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \le 2$. I am wondering what the thought processes would be behind choosing this stronger claim *specifically*-how can we know that this stronger claim will be correct and furnish a fruitful result before we go on to prove it? What makes us choose $2-\frac{1}{n}$ for the RHS of our stronger claim specifically, rather than any other expression involving $n$? Are there any constraints on what we can subtract from 2?

I would like to know this to make sure that I can replicate the thought processes of this proof- I am not sure that I would have seen which stronger claim to prove after not getting anywhere with the weaker claim.

Comment: In this particular case, the stronger claim is chosen because the weaker claim cannot really be used to prove the inductive step. Adding $1/n^2$ to something $\leq 2$ doesn't imply that it's still $\leq 2$. But if you add $1/n^2$ to something $\leq 2-1/n$, then the claim certainly does hold.

Comment: However, the question "how do I know when to strengthen/generalize my claim" *in general* is extremely hard. Mathematicians develop entire theories to answer tricky questions by generalizing the framework often in spectacular fashion. Think of this problem as a small taste of this much larger lesson.

Comment: @Nico is there any reason why we would choose 2−1/n specifically rather than any other  expression using n?

Comment: Simply because $(x-1/n)+1/n^2  \leq 2$ if $x\leq 2$ ($x$ being the sum in the inductive hypothesis). You could choose many other expressions $f(n)$, so long as $f(n) + 1/n^2\leq 0$.

Comment: @Nico is it $\frac {1}{(n+1)^2}$ not $\frac {1}{n^2}$ here? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Nico Also what is the reason why f(n) +1/n^2 has to be less than zero? Is it because then the sum up to k+1 could be bigger than 2, which we can't prove because we are assuming it is smaller than 2? I am confused as to why this is important.

Comment: I made some comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4669529/proving-an-inequality-using-elementary-manipulations/4669586#4669586) about choosing various forms and seeing how to apply them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never forget that mathematical induction is merely ***a*** (`/ˈeɪ/`) way of proving propositions. One sometimes has to improve prepositions slightly so that mathematical induction is applicable.

---

It is easy to see that for any integer $n$ higher than $1$,
$$
\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{(n-1)n} = \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Hence for any integer $n$ higher than $1$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
    1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n^2}
    \leq {} & 1 + \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + \dots + \frac{1}{(n-1)n}
\\
    = {} & 1 + 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}
\\
    = {} & 2 - \frac{1}{n}.
\\
\end{aligned}
$$

I wish that the argument explains why there is $-\frac{1}{n}$.

---

It is less easy to see that for any positive integer $n$,
$$
\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{4}{4n^2} < \frac{4}{4n^2 - 1} = \frac{4}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}
= \frac{2}{2n-1} - \frac{2}{2n+1}.
$$
Hence for any positive integer $n$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
    1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n^2}
    < {} & \frac{2}{1} - \frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3} - \frac{2}{5} + \dots + \frac{2}{2n-1} - \frac{2}{2n+1}
\\
    = {} & 2 - \frac{2}{2n+1}.
\\
\end{aligned}
$$
The estimation is less good than the one that you suggested, but it will still work, if you just wish to show that
$$
1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n^2} \leq 2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider how to set up the stronger statement that will allow us to proceed by induction on $\sum \frac{1}{i^2} \leq 2 - f_n$.

The most important criteria are:

1. $ 2 - f_n + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \leq 2 - f_{n+1}$ for all large enough $n$ so that we can do the induction
2. $ \lim f_n = 0 $ (so that the original statement holds)

We could also consider
3. $ \frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n^2} \leq 2 - f_n$  for a small enough base case $n$, but it's not that important other than having to verify numerous cases.

Let's consider what $f_n$ could look like, esp to satisfy the first criteria:

Criteria 1 is: $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < f_n - f_{n+1}$. This gives us a lower bound on the first difference, which is in some ways like a derivative. This suggests that we should look at $f_n \sim n^{-1}$. This naturally satisfies criteria 2.

- If we try $f_n \sim n^r$ with $r < -1$, show that $f_n - f_{n+1} < \frac{1}{n+1}^2$ eventually.
- If we try $ f_n = \frac{c}{n}$, then the condition is equivalent to $cn+c > n$.

  - This is clearly satisfied for $c = 1$. Now just check criteria 3.
  - For any $ c < 1$, this will not be true for a large enough $n$, thereby it will not work for us.
  - For any $c>1$, when we check criteria 3, we notice that it's not true for $n = 1$. However, that's still find, if we can find another $n$ to use as our base case.
- If we try $f_n = \frac{1}{n+c}$, then the condition is equivalent to $n+1 > c(c+2n+1)$

  - This is clearly satisfied for $c = \frac{1}{2}$ (and even for a slightly larger $c$, esp for large enough $n$). Now just check criteria 3.
- Suppose we want to try $f_n = \frac{c}{\sqrt{n} } $ , then the condition becomes $c \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n} }> \frac{ \sqrt{n} } { \sqrt{(n+1)^3}} $.

  - We could even try $ \frac{ 0.9} { \sqrt{n}}$ and see how that goes.
- We could get more creative, like trying out things like $ \frac{cn}{n^2 - 1 }$, $\frac{ n+c } { n^2}$, etc.

  - In general, simplicity is better.